# grunt-contrib-handlebars - Output is different than when I run the handlebars npm task

Tags: javascript, compilation, coffeescript, handlebars.js, gruntjs

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

I'm trying to precompile handlebars (.hbs) templates using grunt-contrib-handlebars

When I run the run task I end up with this:

```
this["JST"] = this["JST"] || {};

this["JST"]["app/templates/err.hbs"] = Handlebars.template(function (Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
  this.compilerInfo = [4,'>= 1.0.0'];
helpers = this.merge(helpers, Handlebars.helpers); data = data || {};
  var buffer = "", stack1, functionType="function", escapeExpression=this.escapeExpression;


  buffer += "<div>Error: ";
  if (stack1 = helpers.error) { stack1 = stack1.call(depth0, {hash:{},data:data}); }
  else { stack1 = depth0.error; stack1 = typeof stack1 === functionType ? stack1.apply(depth0) : stack1; }
  buffer += escapeExpression(stack1)
    + "</div>";
  return buffer;
  });
```

However, if I run the npm handlebars module from terminal I get this:

```
(function() {
  var template = Handlebars.template, templates = Handlebars.templates = Handlebars.templates || {};
templates['err.hbs'] = template(function (Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
  this.compilerInfo = [4,'>= 1.0.0'];
helpers = this.merge(helpers, Handlebars.helpers); data = data || {};
  var buffer = "", stack1, functionType="function", escapeExpression=this.escapeExpression;


 buffer += "<div>Error: ";
 if (stack1 = helpers.error) { stack1 = stack1.call(depth0, {hash:{},data:data}); }
 else { stack1 = depth0.error; stack1 = typeof stack1 === functionType ? stack1.apply(depth0) : stack1; }
 buffer += escapeExpression(stack1)
   + "</div>";
 return buffer;
 });
})();
```

The second compiled template (run from terminal) works correctly in my app - but the one that grunt creates does not. Could someone perhaps point me in the right direction with what I might be doing wrong here?

My gruntfile looks like this:

```
handlebars:
       options:
                wrapped: true
       compile:
                files: 'www/js/templates.js': ['app/templates/*.hbs']
```

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You can avoid the namespace by setting the option `namespace` to false, however I'm not sure you can get your output the same as it used to be using only the npm package. Note that the versions might be different!

Comment: Thanks Anzeo - the namspace issue is helpful. I still need to figure out why the rest of the output is different though. Any other thoughts?

Comment: pixelworlds, I'm afraid I haven't found a solution yet to achieve this. When I moved from the npm variant to the grunt package, I eventually chose to update how my Handlebars compiled templates were used in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was a problem caused by using different versions of Handlebars where the grunt-contrib-handlebars version was different then the globally installed handlebars npm module.

Comment: Bit late in the day, but how can you determine the versions?  I have the same issue despite apparently having the same version of handlebars installed in the project and globally?

Comment: Believe it or not I am also still dealing with this issue in 2020. Any chance you still have access to this project and can provide the versions used?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a function as "processName" and specify a "namespace" in Gruntfile, for example something like this if you have only one file `article_snippet.handlebars` in a single folder called `handlebars` could do the job:

```
    handlebars: {
      compile: {
        options: {
          namespace: 'Handlebars.templates',
          processName: function(filename) {
              var name = filenaname.split('/')[1].split('.');
              return name[0];
          },
          wrapped: true,
          commonjs: null
        },
        files: {
          "js/articles/templates.js": "handlebars/article_snippet.handlebars",
        }
      }
    },
```

taking inspiration from [grunt-contrib-handlebars doc](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-handlebars#namespace)